# Разная работа скрипта при нажатии на одну и ту же кнопку

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Есть такой скрпит Jquery

```
 var $head = $('.header');
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $('.mobile-snap').click(function() {
    $('.nav-top').hide();
        $head.removeClass('mobile-nav-opened');
  });
$('.mobile-snap').click(function() {
    $head.addClass('mobile-nav-opened');
    $('.nav-top').show();
  });
  });
```

Не очень силен в теме, но вроде как при нажатии на один и тот же элемент два противополодных действия сделать нельзя. В моем случае при нажатии на `.mobile-snap` в первый раз нужно чтобы сначала добавлялся класс к элементу и открывалась менюшка, а затем удалялся класс и закрывалась менюшка. Такой код не работает ксж. Может кто поможет? Спасибо

Comment: Проверяете в каком статусе например nav-top и делаете соответствующие действия.

Comment: Или совсем просто toggle/toggleClass.

Comment: С тогглом проще получилось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение благодаря совету u_malder:

> Проверяете в каком статусе например nav-top и делаете соответствующие
>   действия.
>
> Или совсем просто toggle/toggleClass.